# Proteger API django rest framework

Tags: python, api, djangorestframework

¿Como se podría proteger una API con django rest framework con autentificación? Es decir, que pida un usuario y una contraseña para poder acceder por ejemplo.

Tengo una API de usuarios, que si entras en la URL `/users/` pues se listan todos los usuarios, y esto podría hacerlo cualquiera. Me gustaría que solo la aplicación tuviese acceso a las rutas de la API, o al menos que solicite un ingreso de autentificación.

¿Hay alguna forma de configurarlo?

Comment: Qué has intentado? DRF ya incluye todo lo necesario para la autentificación de usuarios: [DRF Authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de proporcionar autenticación / autorización a un servicio:

La autenticación se basa, simplemente, en saber que alguien es quien dice ser. Es como cuando la policía te pide una identificación, necesitan saber quien eres en realidad, no quien dices ser.

Por otro lado tenemos la autorización. Este proceso es el encargado de decir si una petición se va a cursar o si se bloquea.

Es importante distinguir estos dos conceptos ya que protocolos como OAuth están diseñados para que cada parte se realice en un servicio diferente, aislando los servicios entre sí a la vez que intenta evitar ataques tipo *man in the middle*

**API KEY**

Esta solución se basa en el uso de secuencias conocidas únicamente por el servicio y sus consumidores autorizados.

Cada vez que un cliente quiere acceder al servicio, debe añadir su API KEY a la petición. El servicio leerá dicha clave y verificará que es una clave válida.

Este mecanismo es facil de implementar pero plantea algunos problemas de seguridad:

- Si quieres identificar todos los clientes, necesitas un API KEY para cada cliente
- Los API KEY son valores constantes que deben ser conocidos a la vez por servicio y cliente. Si el cliente es distribuído, modificar dicho API KEY puede ser complicado
- Este mecanismo suele estar más recomendado para comunicaciones entre servicios

**Autenticación HTTP**

También puedes configurar una autenticación básica usando los mecanismos de HTTP.

El problema que presenta esta solución es que toda la gestión de usuarios corre por tu cuenta. Además, si no utilizas HTTPS corres el riesgo de que se puedan interceptar facilmente las credenciales

Puedes ver un ejemplo [aquí](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/basic-authentication-django-rest-framework/)

**Token de sesión**

Este es un mecanismo un poco más complejo pero es mucho más dinámico y versátil

Para implementarlo necesitas hacer uso de un servicio de autenticación. Este servicio, por ejemplo uno basado en OAuth como [Okta](https://www.okta.com/), [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) o [Identity Server](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Este servicio se encarga de validar que un usuario es quien dice ser, tras lo cual le proporciona un token de sesión el cual caducará pasado un tiempo prudencial.

Los tokens de sesión (como los JWT) incluyen información sobre el usuario que ha iniciado sesión. Normalmente los servidores de autenticación suelen dejar en manos del usuario la cantidad de información que se expone en estos tokens de sesión. Por seguridad interesa exponer la menor cantidad de información posible. De hecho, solo con el id de usuario debería bastar.

Los siguientes pasos, a implementar en tu servicio, consisten en leer este token de sesión y procesarlo para decidir si la petición llega a buen término o no:

- Validar que el token de sesión no está caducado
- Comprobar que el token es válido
- Verificar si el usuario (su información está en el token de sesión) tiene permitido realizar peticiones al endpoint actual

Para hacer todo esto, en el caso de django, necesitas hacer uso de un [toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). La configuración final de tu servicio dependerá de los requisitos que tengas/quieras cumplir.

Puedes ver un ejemplo de uso [aquí](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_03.html)